Why would Linux on Docker desktop on Windows 10 grow indefinitely?
I have a Docker Desktop ext4 file that is growing from 8GB to 440GB. The Docker commands show that space is ok or using at most 20GB between container and images. In any case I already tried deleting all containers.
Why does the OS storage consumption increase if only using images and containers, and not installing anything within the OS itself?
Docker commands:
C:\>docker system df
TYPE            TOTAL     ACTIVE    SIZE      RECLAIMABLE
Images          6         6         6.395GB   0B (0%)
Containers      6         6         578.6MB   0B (0%)
Local Volumes   0         0         0B        0B
Build Cache     119       0         0B        0B

Linux command shows this:
$ sudo df -h
Filesystem                                Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
none                                      3.9G  4.0K  3.9G   1% /mnt/wsl
none                                      3.9G  8.0K  3.9G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/shared-sockets/host-services
/dev/sdc                                 1007G   57M  956G   1% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/docker-desktop-user-distro
none                                      475G  456G   20G  96% /usr/lib/wsl/drivers
/dev/sde                                 1007G  1.9G  954G   1% /
...
snapfuse                                  131M  131M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/1284
snapfuse                                  132M  132M     0 100% /snap/ubuntu-desktop-installer/1286
/dev/loop0                                427M  427M     0 100% /mnt/wsl/docker-desktop/cli-tools
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources  475G  456G   20G  96% /Docker/host

In the Windows folder, there are not 475GB, at most 2 GB.
Edit: Adding image from windirstats FYI, I was able to claim some space by compacting but still a lot of space is occupied but I don't know with what.

Edit: I let it run for a couple of weeks and 5GBs disappeared, same container load running in both cases, just some docker build and container recreation from scratch in between


Usually because of logs filling up in the container.

I regularly delete containers, but I will do again with all of them. That space should show up in the docker stats and it does not, but will try

Instead of guessing you could just look into the container where the space is used.

Nah, it is not that, I even tried to docker system prune afterwards and it claimed 0B

docker df is somewhat of a joke. Check manually what consumes space.

I am trying with different variations of du -a but I already tried killing all containers, and I know images are not the issue, so it has to be underlying linux

Which ext4 file are you talking about? “Data” or “distro”? The “distro” image shouldn’t grow at all, it stores no operational data. The “data” image holds all those images and containers you are working with. Depending on peak data volume, it may grow a lot.

@DanielB it is docker_data, I added an image in the question

Okay, so basically you have the classic “WSL 2 ate my disk” problem and all existing information about that around the net applies. There may not be an easy solution, I don’t remember exactly.

I just recreated docker from scratch and doing a du every few days... lets see if I can figure out

It's not about du (what's inside the VM). It's about WSL 2 not shrinking the virtual disk.

But why would that happen? so it is really a misterious bug? I have been monitoring the whole thing for 8 days already and the size does not grow but I do the same operations I did before.

Docker keeps tracks of each and every modified file, and all previous versions. So, you must locate variable directories outside of the container. /var/log is one obvious candidate.
If you use a database inside your docker container, the directory for your data must also be outside of the container.
You can reduce the number of layers with "docker export" followed by "docker import". This action will only keep the uppermost layer of the files, discarding all previous versions and therefore reducing the size of the container

I tried to delete images completely but that did not reclaim any space (beyond the image itself)
